# why i am not getting any response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

```
data class NewsResponse(
    val articles: List<Article>,
    val status: String,
    val totalResults: Int
)   

data class Source(
    val id: String,
    val name: String
)

data class Article(
    val author: String,
    val content: String,
    val description: String,
    val publishedAt: String,
    val source: Source,
    val title: String,
    val url: String,
    val urlToImage: String
)

object RetrofitHelper {

    fun getInstances():Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://newsapi.org/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }
}

interface NewsService {

 @GET("v2/everything?")

 suspend fun getNews(@Query("country")country:String,@Query("page")page:Int,@Query("apiKey")apiKey:String):Response<NewsResponse>

}
```

**This below code is written on MainActivity**

```
val newsservice=RetrofitHelper.getInstances().create(NewsService::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val result=newsservice.getNews(country,page, apiKey)
            if(result.isSuccessful){

                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"HEllo World",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                 val list=result.body()!!.articles
                list.forEach {
                      Log.d(debug,it.source.id)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: which error are thrown? are you provide any log?

Comment: there is no error but nothing showing in my logcat of TAG debug

Comment: Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"HEllo World",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()  must be shown on UI thread or main thread. In this case you try to show toast in background thread

Comment: And Catch error using try catch block.

Comment: Add a log statement in the else block to `result.isSuccessful`. See if that gets printed.

Comment: @ArpitShukla else block is executing

Comment: @ArpitShukla can you tell me why api call is unsuccessful

Comment: Log the error message. That will tell you the reason of failure. It should be something like `response.error.toString()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected my mistake  @Query("country")  this was wrong i have to use @Query("q") thats my result giving null list